# How to force flex-row into 2x2 grid on certain window size?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, row, react-bootstrap

I'm not very experienced with react-bootstrap. I'm working on this code which renders four buttons in a `flex-row`:

```
renderBoxes(boxes) {
        return Object.keys(boxes).map((key, index) => {
            var box = boxes[key];
            return <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12 d-flex flex-row" key={index}>
                <IconBox
                    key={index}
                    title={box.title}
                    description={box.description}
                    icon={box.icon}
                    link={box.link}
                />
            </div>
        });
    }

<div className="row d-flex flex-row">
    {this.renderBoxes(boxes)}
</div>
```

At `lg` window widths, the buttons look like this:
[image]

At `md` window widths, the buttons look like this, in a 2x2 grid:
[image]

However, at `sm` window widths, the buttons begin displaying one on top of the other:
[image]

I want to force the buttons to stay in the 2x2 grid at all of the screen sizes including and smaller than `md`. Is there any way to achieve this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is giving class of `col-lg-3` for larger devices and then the second class `col-6` and that's it. So when screen get smaller than `lg` the button will always remain in `2x2`grid and never going to fall into single column.

```
renderBoxes(boxes) {
  return Object.keys(boxes).map((key, index) => {
      var box = boxes[key];
      return <div className="col-lg-3 col-6 d-flex flex-row" key={index}>
          <IconBox
              key={index}
              title={box.title}
              description={box.description}
              icon={box.icon}
              link={box.link}
          />
      </div>
  });
}

<div className="row">
{this.renderBoxes(boxes)}
</div>
```

---

One extra thing i want to tell you

`xs` is now removed from `bootstrap` so you can use `col-6` instead of `col-xs-6`

so in the future if you are setting different `resolution devices` then you can do this

```
<div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12"> some text </div>
```